# MVC 6: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I got this error in my staging environment but don't get it in my local environment. The staging server is Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The staging environment was working at one point and this error is recent. I get this error from the error log. The site just spins and does not display anything.

Both environments have the same dnx version

```
C:\Users\Me>dnx --version
Microsoft .NET Execution environment
Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16609
Type:         Clr
Architecture: x86
OS Name:      Windows
OS Version:   6.1
Runtime Id:   win7-x86
```

The solution is using dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2.

I added the package 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource' to all projects in the solution and deployed it. That did nothing.

I grabbed the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll from the packages directory and dropped it into 'runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin' directory. I then get an error this error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.1.0
```

I placed the System.Numerics.Vectors.dll into the bin directory like I did with the DiagnosticSource.dll but I still get the missing Vectors.dll error. I don't believe I should be placing DLLs into the runtime bin directory. How do I solve this?

Update

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
   1.0.0-beta8       clr     x86          win
   1.0.0-beta8       coreclr x86          win
   1.0.0-rc1-final   clr     x64          win
   1.0.0-rc1-final   clr     x86          win
   1.0.0-rc1-final   coreclr x64          win
   1.0.0-rc1-final   coreclr x86          win
   1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
   1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win
   1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
   1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
  *1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr     x86          win             default
```

Comment: You should not be copying dlls that are in packages to random places. What version of .NET Framework do you have on the machine where things don't work?

Comment: @Pawel - I copied the DLLs only for debugging purposes. Updated to list versions of .NET.

Comment: Could you please post your project.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not .Net Framework 4 installed. Normally the assembly like System.Numerics.Vectors should be loaded from GAC not from local bin directory.